# Folder in SharePoint document library is deleted still its URL works

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have deleted on folder from my Document library, that folder does not appear now in library, but when I tried to open that folder by its URL, it open the folder. Though I am not able to add anything in it, but still it should throw an error or something.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did it deleted from receyle bin? also try to clear the browser cache and try again or use different browser?

Comment: I tried all of it. I deleted that folder from recycle bin, cleared browser cache and also i tried that URL in different browser and it opens that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did research on this and found out that this is the known bug in SharePoint 2010. We cannot do anything with this.

Thank you for your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't checked your second stage recycle bin, kindly do so . Else open up SharePoint Designer to the site in question, go to the list or library, rename the folder, then delete.